# The alignment property of the Align class is not working in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to move my container to the top left with the help of the Align class within a stack but the container is not moving from its place. I also tried the Positioned widget, but the Positioned widget is making the container invisible. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.
**Code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // device size
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        height: size.height,
        width: size.width,
        child: Stack( // stack takes in all the space of the device
          children: <Widget>[
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment(0, 0), // this doesn't work
              child: Container(
                height: 200,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Edit: The Positioned widget and the Align are working perfectly now after starting the app again by stoping it.

Comment: try Positioned widget

Comment: As I already said, the Positioned widget is also not working. It just makes the container invisible.

Answer (score 1):

Try `alignment: Alignment.topLeft`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Testtt extends StatelessWidget {
  const Testtt({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // device size
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        height: size.height,
        child: Stack(
          // stack takes in all the space of the device
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 200,
              width: size.width,
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: Container(
                  width: 200,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: It goes to the top but doesn't go to the left.

Comment: Try `alignment: Alignment(-1, -1)`

Comment: Stays the same as Alignment.topLeft

Comment: Give your container width also `width:200`

Comment: I want the width to be as same as the screen size.

Comment: Ok then you can wrap the circle with a SizedBox that has the same width as the screen size, but the circle must have a fixed width.

`SizedBox(height: 200,width:size.width,child:Align(alignment:Alignment.topLeft,child: Container(width:200,decoration: const BoxDecoration(color:Colors.red,shape:BoxShape.circle,),),),)`

Comment: It doesn't work. It stays same as previous

Comment: @dipansh I have editted the original answer, I also attached a photo with the result. I don't know why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Yeah! It works now. But isn't there any other direct way to do that because right now it looks more like a fix. I mean can't I just simply align the container without using SizedBox?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your widget with `Position()` or `AnimatedPosition()` and specify :`top:0, left:0`

Answer (score 0):

Assigns some width to the Positioned widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // device size
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        height: size.height,
        width: size.width,
        child: Stack(
          fit: StackFit.loose,
          // stack takes in all the space of the device
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
              top: 0,
              left: 0,
              width: 200,
              child: Container(
                height: 200,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try one of this two snippets.

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    color: Colors.blue,
    height: size.height,
    width: size.width,
    child: Stack( 
      children: <Widget>[
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter, 
          child: Container(
            height: 200,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);

return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    color: Colors.blue,
    height: size.height,
    width: size.width,
    child: Stack( 
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      children: <Widget>[
        Positioned(
          top: 0,
          left: 0, 
          child: Container(
            height: 200,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```